# VB.NET Linq join query not returning all values?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two tables as follows:

model datatable Columns: make, series, model

association datatable Columns: make, series, part#

I am trying to do the following join to get make, series, model, part#
The problem is, I am only getting 11 results, where there should be 285?

```
Dim query = _
            From m In db.DeviceModels.AsEnumerable()
            Join c In db.Comp.AsEnumerable()
            On c.Field(Of String)("make") Equals m.Field(Of String)("make") And
            c.Field(Of String)("series") Equals m.Field(Of String)("series")
            Select New With {
                .make = m.Field(Of String)("make"), _
                .series = m.Field(Of String)("series"), _
                .model = m.Field(Of String)("model"), _
                .oem = c.Field(Of String)("oem") _
            }
```

Can anyone find something wrong with this query that it would only return 11 results instead of the 285 that it should?

I have debugged and verified that all the data is there. I have also converted it to a sql query and performed it on the same data but in sql server to verify that I should be getting 285 result rows.

Comment: If you look at one of the 11 that are returned and one of the 274 that aren't, do you see any difference in the make / series variables in the Devicemodels / Comp enumerables?

Comment: Can you show us your sql equivalent of this linq query?

Comment: Without a [mcve] or the data it's hard to know what is going on.  One thing to consider... in SQL Server, string comparison will ignore trailing spaces, but that is not the case in a LINQ query against a DataTable.  I used your query against some test data and it seems to work ok, so it's probably an issues with your particular data.

Comment: Try a `Group Join`